# Can't update a column for its formatted values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know what's wrong but I just cant update it. I get the correct result set when formating the date but when I update it into the actual table (no error when executing) it's just the same data.

Table Structure is as follows:

```
UNIDAD VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL;
TIPO_DOC nchar(10) NOT NULL,
NUMERO_DOC int NOT NULL,
MES nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
FECHA date NOT NULL,  --the one that matters
NIT_CLIENTE nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
NOMBRE_CLIENTE nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
INGRESO money NOT NULL;
```

This is the statement I've been executing (with no results):

```
UPDATE INCOME
SET INCOME.FECHA=FO.FECHA
FROM INCOME
JOIN(
    SELECT INCOME.NUMERO_DOC, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), INCOME.FECHA, 101)
        AS FECHA FROM INCOME
) FO ON FO.NUMERO_DOC = INCOME.NUMERO_DOC
WHERE FO.NUMERO_DOC = INCOME.NUMERO_DOC
```

Please help.

Comment: What's the primary key for your `INCOME` table?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change, it looks (to me) like you just converted the `FECHA` date to a date, which is already was, so... this appears to be the desired result?

Comment: I mean, `FECHA` is a `date` data type, you can't update it to give it a format, it doesn't really make sense

Comment: Im formatting the original date(yyyy-mm-dd) to (mm-dd-yyyy) and updating it, by doing so only with select i get the correct data, however it doesnt update the old date when i execute the update statement

Comment: it doesn't because `date` doesn't have an implicit format. If you want the results in a particular format, then use that in the `SELECT`

Comment: You cannot change the structure of the date data type with an update query like this. It's just holding the date, its format doesn't matter in the structure of the table itself. You can modify that formatting through a `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the output format of a Date field by updating it with a formatted date. The default output format of a date field is controlled by the server settings.

You have three choices to do what you seem to desire:

1. Change the default date format of the server.
2. Use a FORMAT or CONVERT statement on every SELECT
3. Create a `Formatted Fecha` varchar field to hold the date in the output/display format you want to use.

Well, you could run your output through a reporting solution, and let that format the date output, but that isn't a SQL Server solution per se.

Comment: I'm gonna check it
It sounds like it's probably that because the update executes correctly and the display shows that the rows were affected

Comment: You can also add a calculated field, e.g. `ALTER TABLE INCOME ADD FormattedFecha = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), INCOME.FECHA, 101)`. Then the date formatting is built into the field output, and it is converted each time you SELECT from the field.

Answer (score 0):

The style code `101` stands for `mm/dd/yyyy` (US standard).

When you update it, SQL Server will implicitly convert it to `YYYY-MM-DD` or based on `regional` configuration.

Based on (in comment)

> Im formatting the original date(yyyy-mm-dd) to (mm-dd-yyyy) and updating it, by doing so only with select i get the correct data

This is not correct, you can still get the desired result by using `where` clause & the only thing is thet you need to convert it explicitly or just use `yyyy-mm-dd` :

```
where convert(varchar(10), FECHA, 101) = 'mm-dd-yyyy' -- which i really don't recommend
```

Use instead :

```
where FECHA = 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

Comment: not necessarily, it will depend on regional configurations